# how to replace many occurrences of comma by single comma

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace

Earlier I had string as `1,2,3,,5,6,7`

To replace string, I used `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",," withString:@","`, which gives output as `1,2,3,5,6,7`

Now I have string as below.

`1,2,3,,,6,7`

To replace string, I used `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",," withString:@","`, which gives output as `1,2,3,,6,7`

Is there way where I can replace all double comma by single comma.

I know I can do it using for loop or while loop, but I want to check is there any other way?

```
for (int j=1;j<=100;j++) {
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",," withString:@","]] 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"1,2,3,,,6,7";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@",{2,}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@","];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

This will match any number of `,` present in the string. It's future proof :)

Answer (score 2):

Not the perfect solution, but what about this

```
NSString *string = @"1,2,3,,,6,7";
NSMutableArray *array =[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
[array removeObject:@""];

NSLog(@"%@",[array componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```